# Turn every basis in a Hilbert space problem into orthonormal.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that the modified shift operator $$T(\phi_k) =\frac{1}{k}\phi_{k+1}$$ is compact (and has no eignvalues) for a general basis $(\phi_k)$ on a Hilbert space.

The ([solutions page 5, bottom](http://www.math.umn.edu/~bahra004/for-real/real2-hw3.pdf)) here keeps pushing the fact that all basis on a Hilbert space must be orthonormal. I understand one can reduce every problem like this by Gram-Schmmidt, but doesn't this defeat the original purpose of the problem? Unless they are saying something else here…

> [image]

I also got some remaining analysis questions.

1. In the blue box, the justification is because all $c_{n,k} \in B(0, 1)$ right? And that their distance can be no more than their diameter?

(does anyone know what happened to the proof-strategy tag? Can't find it anywhere.)

Comment: Added: this might be included in the definition of "basis of a Hilbert space" (in your course).

Comment: It might be, because my book states the Spectrum theorem as "there exists a basis (orthonormal) that consists of eigenvectors…" but there are times when it doesn't state it is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: And what is the definition of "basis"?

Comment: My book has the definition of an algebraic basis and an orthonormal basis. The algebraic one is more or less the one we know in linear algebra (they include stuff about Axiom of Choice).

Comment: Then I would say they refer to 'orthonormal basis' when they simply say 'basis' in a Hilbert space context.

Comment: If you have an algebraic basis $\{ \phi_k \}_{k}$ for a Hilbert space $H$, then either the basis is uncountable or $H$ is finite-dimensional. If the basis is uncountable, then your expression for $T$ makes no sense unless you are indexing the basis with an element of $\mathbb{R}$. So I think you're left with the conclusion that the basis is countable, and must be a complete orthonormal basis.